# Fast algorithm to invert an ARGB color value to ABGR?

Tags: java, android, algorithm, colors

I'm using `IntBuffer` to manipulate pixels of a Bitmap, but the value in the buffer should be **AABBGGRR**, while the color constants are **AARRGGBB**. I know I can use `Color.argb`, `Color.a`, ... to invert, but I think it's not perfect.

I need to manipulate a very large number of pixels, so I need an algorithm that can perform this operator in short time. I think of this Bit Expression, but it's not correct:

```
0xFFFFFFFF ^ pSourceColor
```

If there's no better one, maybe I will use bit-shift operators (that performs `Color.a`, ...) instead of calling the functions to reduce the time.

**EDIT:**

This is my current function to convert, though I think there shoul be a better algorithm (less operators) to perform it:

```
private int getBufferedColor(final int pSourceColor) {
    return
            ((pSourceColor >> 24) << 24) |          // Alpha
            ((pSourceColor >> 16) & 0xFF) |         // Red  -> Blue
            ((pSourceColor >> 8) & 0xFF) << 8 |     // Green
            ((pSourceColor) & 0xFF) << 16;          // Blue -> Red
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert RGB to BGR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041499/how-to-convert-rgb-to-bgr)

Comment: No, that topic only discuss about RGB. And the good answers are actually using bit shift to get red, green, blue. My problem is more advanced, as Alpha doesn't switch position.

Comment: 1) There is no way to solve this (in a performant manner) without using bitshifting and 2) The best way to do it is in that answer. In your case, just save the alpha, shift it out, and then add it back at the end.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since A and G are in place, you can probably do a little better by masking off the B and R and then adding them back. Haven't tested it but ought to be 95% right:

```
private static final int EXCEPT_R_MASK = 0xFF00FFFF;
private static final int ONLY_R_MASK = ~EXCEPT_R_MASK;
private static final int EXCEPT_B_MASK = 0xFFFFFF00;
private static final int ONLY_B_MASK = ~EXCEPT_B_MASK;

private int getBufferedColor(final int pSourceColor) {
    int r = (pSourceColor & ONLY_R_MASK) >> 16;
    int b = pSourceColor & ONLY_B_MASK;
    return
      (pSourceColor & EXCEPT_R_MASK & EXCEPT_B_MASK) | (b << 16) | r;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, the following function is **fast enough** to return the **ABGR** color while passing an **ARGB** color and **vice-versa!**

```
int argbToABGR(int argbColor) {
    int r = (argbColor >> 16) & 0xFF;
    int b = argbColor & 0xFF;
    return (argbColor & 0xFF00FF00) | (b << 16) | r;
}
```